# VBA Unicode that works in 32-bit Windows fails in 64-bit

Tags: vba, unicode, 32bit-64bit

In MS Word, there are previously written, fully functional, 32-bit VBA commands that contain Unicode characters coded such as this: `ChrW(&H2191)`. Now in 64-bit Windows with the 64-bit version of Microsoft Office, such code triggers this error message:

> Compile error: Can't find project or library.

`ChrW$(&H2191)` returns the same message.

Why is this error occurring?

In VBA "Tools > References" there's nothing listed as missing.

Despite much sleuthing, I can't pinpoint the problem although I sense the 64-bit environment is involved somehow.

Comment: `ChrW(&H2191)` works just fine on my 64-bit Windows machine. Do you have a 64-bit version of Microsoft Office? (Mine is 32-bit.) If you type `?ChrW(&H2191)` in the immediate window, do you get that same error? If not, please post the code that does.

Comment: Yes, MS Office is the 64-bit version.
Yes, ?ChrW(&H2191) generates the same error message.

Comment: The ChrW function works fine in 64-bit office. Your problem is most likely related to something completely unrelated to Unicode.